# Displaying the text based on conditions getting blank in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my database having a column as status.By default if any user add the data it will be added as 0. While fetching the data from database if i write condition it is displaying as blank.

If status is equal to zero it should display the text as active and if status is equal to 1 it should display the text as deactive.

Here is my code which i have written but it is not working.

```
                <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Blog Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Hits</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(3)+0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>
                    <tr>

                        <td class="align-center"><?php echo $i;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->blog_title;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->date;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->ne_views;?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/blogs/edit/<?php echo $row ->blog_id ;?>" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/blogs/delete/<?php echo $row ->blog_id ;?>"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                            <a class="button active" href="<?php echo site_url()?>/blogs/active/<?php echo $row ->blog_id ;?>"
                            <?php if($row->status==1){echo 'Deactive="Deactive"';} else{echo 'Active="Active"';}?>></a>
                            <a class="button preview" target="_blank" href="<?php echo site_url()?>/blogs/preview/<?php echo $row ->blog_id ;?>">Preview</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                 <?php  } ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: your `$row` might be array not object try `$row['blog_id']` instead of `$row->blog_id`

Comment: In the controller side, if you are getting database results by using function `results_array()` then you should be using `$row['blog_id']` because that will return results array, not object. To get results as an object, you can use `result();` See this: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: @VijaySharma not getting  what you are saying

Comment: @user6728960 replace `$row->blog_id` to `$row['blog_id']` and `$row->status` to `$row['status']` and check

Comment: @VijaySharma if i change that it is displaying only one record in the list.Can you please check my updated question

Comment: @user6728960 just do one thing comment hole code just use `echo "<pre>";print_r($records);die;` after that what you will get output that you share

Comment: @user6728960 and can you enable`error reporting` so you can check what mistake you did

Comment: @VijaySharma  go this  after adding this line Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [blog_id] => 20
            [image_path] => 
            [blog_title] => sample blog for testing
            [description] => sample blog for testing
            [status] => 0
            [ne_views] => 1
            [position] => 
            [category_id] => 
            [blogtitle] => sample_blog_for_testing
            [date] => 2017-08-30
            [blog_name] => blog
            [blog_writer] => admin
            [featured_blogs] => 1
        )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154293/discussion-between-vijay-sharma-and-user6728960).

Comment: use $row[0]->status instead of $row->status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<a class="button" href="<?=site_url('blogs/').(($row->status==1)?'/delete/':'/active/').$row ->blog_id ;?>"> <?=($row->status==1)?'Active':'De-active';?></a>
```

If Status is zero the `url` is deactive and 
if Status is one the `url` is Active